# Proof of a limit as $x\to 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I have been working on this one for some time now.

I was able to calculate the limit of $f(x)=|x|$ as $x\to 0$, yet I am unable to prove my result.

I tried using the $\varepsilon\text{-}\delta$ definition of a limit of a function, yet it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try $\delta=\epsilon$

Comment: Could you show us what you tried exactly?

Comment: Essentially, I did not think that my proof was correct because epsilon always ended up equaling to delta. So I had the correct proof, yet I thought it was wrong and continued looking for other ways to prove it.

Comment: @DanaShay : $\delta=\varepsilon$ is just what is needed in this case.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yep, it worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: There's nothing that says $\delta$ can't be $\epsilon$ or even that then need to be related. Nor is there anything that says there is only one possible delta.  $\delta = \epsilon$ should be expected as $|x|$ and $x$ grow and shrink at more or less the same rate (they are basically the same thing but for sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0. $ Then we can choose $\delta=\varepsilon$ such that $|x-0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-0|=||x|-0|<\delta=\varepsilon$ which proves the limit value of the given function at $0$ is $0.$